# Bring up all terminal windows to front of screen?

Tags: x11, window-management

I usually have 2-3 terminals open when programming on Fedora, but I find it quite tedious having to click and manually bring every terminal to the front screen when I compile and run.

Are there any hotkeys / tools that will bring all terminals to the front of the screen?

Comment: Why don't you just use your virtual workspaces? What Desktop Environment or Window Manager are you using?

Comment: @Ramonvski I had tagged fedora 18 but it was removed for some reason.

Comment: I think someone removed that tag given this is a generic question, not really fedora 18 specific.

Comment: You could use a single terminal window split using `GNU Screen` or `tmux`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `xdotool` to achieve what you want. The [main project page](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool) is over on github. You could do something like this for example:

```
xdotool behave_screen_edge bottom-left search --class gnome-terminal windowactivate
```

This will give you a hot corner in the lower left which will activate all the windows that are a member of the class gnome-terminal. This is by far the easiest method I've seen to accomplish things like this in X.

`xdotool` is pretty easy to use and looks to be in most of the major distros' repositories. You can check out the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/xdotool.1.html) as well. There are several examples to get you started in there along with some [example scripts](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/tree/master/examples) under the github repository.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @ramnovski, put the windows on a seperate desktop. You can switch there as part of your compile/run with `wmctrl -s NUM`.

If you don't want separate desktops, you can also raise a window with `wmctrl -a <WIN>`, where `<WIN>` is one of the several ways of selecting a window that `wmctrl` supports (matching against window title or window id).

If the titles are not unique, record the window IDs with `xwininfo` and store them. You can also do that programmatically, e.g. by opening a file with a UUID based name editing, have wmctrl find the window based on the UUID in the title and then discard that edit.

Answer (score 0):

you should try [Guake Terminal](http://guake.org/).

It appear and disappear by pressing F12,can have multiple tabs, which you can switch using keyboard shortcut.